# Primefaces 3.3, POM, tomcat 7.0.39 and Jboss as EAP 5.1

Tags: maven, jboss, primefaces, tomcat7, pom.xml

I'm working with primefaces 3.3 and JSF 2.0. And the structure of the pom below, when I generate a war, run (work) only on tomcat 7.0.39. I would like to know what I need to change the pom for the war also run in the JBoss EAP 5.1.

**Error:19:19:53,125 SEVERE [config] Critical error during deployment: 
com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: Factory 'javax.faces.context.ExternalContextFactory' was not configured properly. at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FactoryConfigProcessor.verifyFactoriesExist(FactoryConfigProcessor.java:305) at**

- O war generated below does not work in the JBoss EAP 5.1

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.mkyong.core</groupId>
<artifactId>OtimizacaoProcessoInterno</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<name>OtimizacaoProcessoInterno</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<dependencies>

    <!-- PrimeFaces -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
        <version>3.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JSF -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.11</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- EL -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
        <artifactId>el-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
               <wtpversion>2.0</wtpversion>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Seems like http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-web-server/tomcat-to-jboss-migration is what you need.

Comment: What's the error have you faced?

Comment: I need a solution, with changes only in the POM with focusing on Jboss, because it works perfectly for Tomcat. And the error is shown below: 2 Answars.
"com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: Factory 'javax.faces.context.ExternalContextFactory' was not configured properly"

Comment: What do I need to change in the POM, to stay with focusing on Jboss?

Answer (score 0):

You could package your maven module as ear. Thus change your packaging to

```
<packaging>ear</packaging>
```

If you want to customize your ear file, you can use the [maven-ear-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ear-plugin/usage.html).